# SELECT statements not grabbing data with Python Flask

Tags: python, sql, flask, mysql-python

Attempting to gather info on a client when they login. The info was previous entered into the database. I am getting all "1"s back except the email value because the user has to enter the email manually so it must be tripping up on retrieving the data from my tables. I think I am missing something in my Python code... Any ideas?

```
from content_management import Content

#form validations
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, PasswordField, validators
#to encrypt the password
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
#for SQL injection
from MySQLdb import escape_string as thwart
import gc
from functools import wraps
from dbconnect import connection

TOPIC_DICT = Content()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login_page():
    error = ''
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(request.form['email']),))
            data = c.fetchone()[3]

            if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):
                email = request.form['email']
                #grab all the clients info
                clientcid = c.execute("SELECT cid FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
                phone = c.execute("SELECT phone FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
                rating = c.execute("SELECT rating FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
                first_name = c.execute("SELECT first_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                last_name = c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                address = c.execute("SELECT address FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                czip = c.execute("SELECT zip FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                reg_date = c.execute("SELECT reg_date FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                conn.commit()
                c.close()
                conn.close()
                gc.collect()


                session['logged_in'] = 'client'
                session['clientcid'] = clientcid
                session['email'] = email
                session['phone'] = phone
                session['rating'] = rating
                session['first_name'] = first_name
                session['last_name'] = last_name
                session['address'] = address
                session['czip'] = czip
                session['reg_date'] = reg_date
                flash("You are now logged in.")
                return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))

            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials, try again."

        gc.collect()
        return render_template("login.html", error = error)

    except Exception as e:
        #flash(e)
        error = "Invalid credentials, try again."
        return render_template("login.html", error = error)
```

**EDIT: Tried the following, but now won't login...**

```
if request.method == "POST":
            data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(request.form['email']),))
            data = c.fetchone()[3]

            if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):
                clientcid = c.fetchone()[0]
                phone = c.fetchone()[1]
                rating = c.fetchone()[4]
                conn.commit()
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                first_name = c.fetchone()[1]
                last_name = c.fetchone()[2]
                address = c.fetchone()[3]
                czip = c.fetchone()[4]
                reg_date = c.fetchone()[5]
                conn.commit()
                c.close()
                conn.close()
```

**EDIT2:** Same as the previous edit, this code fails to confirm the login credentials even tho the email and password are correct. As soon as I revert back to the first code block I posted, it will confirm the login (with those same credentials), but will have '1's still in every variables but the email.

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login_page():
    error = ''
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(request.form['email']),))
            data = c.fetchone()[3]
            password = request.form['password']

            if password == data:
                email = request.form['email']
                #grab all the clients info
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
                clients_table = c.fetchall()
                clientcid = clients_table[0]
                phone = clients_table[1]
                rating = clients_table[4]
                conn.commit()

                c.execute("SELECT * FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                cpersonals_table = c.fetchall()
                first_name = cpersonals_table[1]
                last_name = cpersonals_table[2]
                address = cpersonals_table[3]
                czip = cpersonals_table[4]
                reg_date = cpersonals_table[5] 
                conn.commit()

                c.close()
                conn.close()

                session['logged_in'] = 'client'
                session['clientcid'] = clientcid
                session['email'] = email
                session['phone'] = phone
                session['rating'] = rating
                session['first_name'] = first_name
                session['last_name'] = last_name
                session['address'] = address
                session['czip'] = czip
                session['reg_date'] = reg_date
                flash("You are now logged in.")
                return redirect(url_for("ask"))

            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials, try again."

        return render_template("login.html", error = error)

    except Exception as e:
        #flash(e)
        error = "Invalid credentials, try again."
        return render_template("login.html", error = error)
```

Comment: Your exception handling is too generic, try to catch more specific errors in less lines of code

Comment: Even my second set of code?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but [point 4](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/top-10-developer-crypto-mistakes/) describes why you should not be using sha256 on passwords.

Comment: @TheGreatContini point 4? What do you mean?

Comment: @douglasrcjames Did you click the link and read the section on "Wrong use or misuse of a cryptographic primitive for password storage"?

Comment: @TheGreatContini wow, I did not see that link! I will read it now.

Comment: @TheGreatContini Okay so I completely removed the sha256.encrypt() function, and am now just comparing a raw password with another raw password but it still won't verify a correct password and email combo. (edit 3: code updated above)

Comment: @douglasrcjames Yikes!  I wasn't trying to make your code less secure!  Again, my comment was not answering your question but instead addressing a different issue.  Once your question is answered, please make your code more secure rather than less secure :-)

Comment: @TheGreatContini Definitely will! Better to get it working insecurely, and then secure it from there